# Dynamically passing a value inside a query?

Tags: c#, sql

I have two columns `syntax` and `query` in my table `Table1`. Syntax contains data called `po` and a query called `select * from po_pomas_pur_order_hdr where pomas_pono =`. I got this query value by using

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select query from Table1 where syntax = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", conn);
```

And my problem is that I need to dynamically pass another value inside the query which I retrived using dataadapter like this:

```
 SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(da.tostring()  +"'"+ textBox1.Text +"'", conn)
```

The resulting query should be like this:

```
 select * from po_pomas_pur_order_hdr where pomas_pono = '2PO/000002/09-10'
```

But it is not possible. How to get a query like this? Any suggestion?

Comment: I can't understand what you exactly want?

Comment: first thing would be to use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of text directly from a (possibly malicious) user.

Comment: from what I understand you want to create a complex SQL query that will give you the result in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SqlDataAdapter` is used to fill datasets and datatables. You cannot obtain the result of a query with `ToString()`. I think you want to use `SqlCommand` to execute your first query to retrieve the actual query to run from the database like this:

```
string query = null;
using (var command = new SqlCommand("select query from Table1 where syntax = @Syntax", conn))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Syntax", textBox1.Text);
    query = command.ExecuteScalar(); // this assumes only one query result is returned
}
```

Then you can use the data adapter to fill it:

```
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(query  +"'"+ textBox1.Text +"'", conn);
```

Although I would suggest to use parameters for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

in this way is more safe: [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

He check the "'" and the "\", check the type of the fields etc...

Code from the example above (is the same for insert delete and update):

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dogs1 WHERE Name LIKE @Name", connection))
    {
    //
    // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
    //
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", dogName));
    //
    // Read in the SELECT results.
    //
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int weight = reader.GetInt32(0);
        string name = reader.GetString(1);
        string breed = reader.GetString(2);
        Console.WriteLine("Weight = {0}, Name = {1}, Breed = {2}", weight, name, breed);
    }
    }
```

Comment: with dataadapter you can use:
 SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebxy9a8b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is example how to use DataAdapter and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have a DataSet you intend to fill using the adapter and that you adjust the queries to use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) in order to avoid [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you should be able to use something like this:

```
string query;
using(var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "select query from Table1 where syntax=@syntax", conn))
{
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("syntax", textBox1.Text);
    query = (string)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
}

using(var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
using(var dataCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameter", poNumber);
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = dataCommand;
    dataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
}
```